# ActiveMQ command lines exception: "Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub"

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.10.0 running on a server, and I'm trying to use the command line to extract the information that I'd see in the [web console](https://activemq.apache.org/web-console).

None of the commands work. In the `bin` folder is the `activemq` script to do run commands, (e.g. `./activemq bstat` or `./activemq list`) but I keep getting this error:

```
Connecting to JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute list task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute list task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
```

Oddly enough, when I download and start the same version of the broker on my local pc, the commands work.  This is the output I get when attempting the `list` command:

```
> activemq list
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_161 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1005056k  free=989327k  max=1005056k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -
...........
<more log data>
...........
useJmxServiceUrl Found JMS Url: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/stub/rO0ABXNyAC5qYXZheC5tYW5hZ2VtZW50LnJlbW90ZS5ybWkuUk1JU2VydmVySW1wbF9TdHViAAAAAAAAAAICAAB4cgAaamF2YS5ybWkuc2VydmVyLlJlbW90ZVN0dWLp/tzJi+FlGgIAAHhyABxqYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN002G0kQxhMx4DAAB4cHc5AAtVbmljYXN0UmVmMgAADjE2OS4yNTQuNjguMjM3AADDoqnwRJwaEyt6UvhZyAAAAXFkS9pNgAEAeA==
Connecting to pid: 3332
brokerName = localhost
```

How do I get the same commands to work that is running on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

So looking at similar issues on StackOverflow and other sites, it seems like I need to add JVM arguments to ActiveMQ when its kicked off.

The **bin** folder of AMQ contains a script `activemq`, in the same bin folder that script kicks off an `activemq.jar` file.

I needed to update part of the script file to include those JVM arguments (in your script don't include the # comments at the end of the line):

```
<script code above>
       # Execute java binary
       if [ -n "$PIDFILE" ] && [ "$PIDFILE" != "stop" ];then

          $EXEC_OPTION $DOIT_PREFIX "$JAVACMD $ACTIVEMQ_OPTS $ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS \
                  -Dactivemq.classpath=\"${ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH}\" \
                  -Dactivemq.home=\"${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}\" \
                  -Dactivemq.base=\"${ACTIVEMQ_BASE}\" \
                  -Dactivemq.conf=\"${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}\" \
                  -Dactivemq.data=\"${ACTIVEMQ_DATA}\" \
                  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \                    #THIS is added
                  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \          #THIS is added
                  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 \      #THIS is added 
                  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \ #THIS is added
                  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \          #THIS is added
                  $ACTIVEMQ_CYGWIN \
                  -jar \"${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/bin/activemq.jar\" $COMMANDLINE_ARGS >/dev/null 2>&1 &
                  RET=\"\$?\"; APID=\"\$!\";
                  echo \$APID > $PIDFILE;
                  echo \"INFO: pidfile created : '$PIDFILE' (pid '\$APID')\";exit \$RET" $DOIT_POSTFIX
          RET="$?"
<script code below>
```

Afterwards I just start the `./activemq` script, and now I'm able to do the Command Lines as I could do on AMQ running on my machine.